# Unable to build a docker image using powershell?

Tags: powershell, docker

When enter the command in powershell I get this error

> "invalid argument "Dockerfile2**" for "-t, --tag" flag: **invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase**

See `docker build --help.`

The Dockerfile I created is in word but I saved it as a plain text.

This is what I typed in my Dockerfile.

```
FROM centos:7    
ENV container docker    
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \

systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \

rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\

rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\

rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \

rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \

rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \

rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\

rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]    
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include "the command" in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are tagging your docker image as "Dockerfile2".
You can't use the Upper case letter for tagging your docker file.
change -t parameter from "Dockerfile2" to "dockerfile2" while building docker image.

Answer (score 1):

Based off the error message, when naming tags, you have to have them in lowercase.

Try changing "Dockerfile2" in your command to the all lowercase: "dockerfile2"

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following in order to be able to build it successfully using Powershell:

- First check Docker is installed on your system by entering "docker --version" command in your powershell. If you see your docker version, you are good to go, otherwise install docker properly.
- Create a simple text (not word document etc.) file called Dockerfile (if you use other file names you will have to specify the file name with -f option)
- Paste your dockerfile entries in it and save the file
- In your powershell, go the path that includes your Dockerfile and run "docker build -t  ."
- check your new image by running "docker image ls"

In my environment, your file was built successfully but there was a warning regarding one of your command in your Dockerfile entries:

[WARNING]: Empty continuation line found in:
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-usemd-tr.target.wants/*;rm -f /etc/systemd/system/.wants/;rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-.getmpfiles-setup.servifs.target.wants/*; rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/udev; rm -f /lib/..wa/systemd/system/.wa.wants/*;rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;                        tm/sts.target.wants/ude
[WARNING]: Empty continuation lines will become errors in a future release.

Comment: So I did everything you said and now the error is saying "unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: GetFileAttributesEx U:\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: I guess you are executing the "docker build -t <yourimagename> ." command in a path that does not contain your Dockerfile. For example, I created my file named as Dockerfile in C:\dockertest\ folder (pasted your dockerfile content inside) and in powershell I cd into the same directory. Then execute "docker build -t test ." you will have an image called test. Instead of test you may use any name you want.